# Is there a page on which I can view all Sitecore jobs running?

Tags: admin-pages, scheduler-job

Straight to the point.

Is there an **admin page in Sitecore which shows all jobs running** and all the information such as *current state*, *name*, *category*, etc?

I used to use the **Sitecore Rocks - Job Viewer** but was wondering if there is such thing embedded directly on the product.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The admin page in the latest Sitecore version has what you are looking for.
Go to /sitecore/admin for the admin overview or directly to `/sitecore/admin/Jobs.aspx`

It will display like this:

[image]

Not sure if it does exactly the same as Rocks but it's a start.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks @gatogordo.